# How to Iterate to Find the Line with Highest Score?

Tags: python, list, split, compare, iteration

I want to know how deal with the following simple file to solve a problem:

```
Query1 
Hit id 1a score 5
Hit id 2a score 3
Hit id 3a score 2

Query2
Hit id 2a score 1
Hit id 2b score 2
```

The problem that I am trying to solve is how to find the Hit that has the highest score value in comparison with the other Hit scores under the same Query.  I expect to get the following output:

```
Query1            # print the title
Hit id 1a score 5 # print the Hit line with highest score value

Query2
Hit id 2b score 2
```

What I have been trying is iterating through the file:

```
for l in file:
    if l.startswith("Query"):
       print l
    elif l.startswith("Hit"):
       l = l.split() #splitting over spaces for each Hit line so I can make 
                     #operation over the score value.
```

Any idea how to compare the parsed score value and output the Hit with the highest score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Continuing on what is given in the question, here is one solution  
file = open('20151122g.dat', 'r')
maxl = None
maxv = 0
for l in file:
    if l.startswith("Query"):
        if not maxl is None:
            print maxl
            maxl = None
            maxv = 0
        print(l)
        continue
    if l.startswith("Hit"):
        col = l.split()
        val = int(col[4])
        if maxv < val:
            maxv = val
            maxl = l
        pass
    pass
if not maxl is None:
    print(maxl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this,

```
>>> s = '''Query1 
Hit id 1a score 5
Hit id 2a score 3
Hit id 3a score 2

Query2
Hit id 2a score 1
Hit id 2b score 2'''
>>> q = s.split('\n\n')
>>> for i in q:
    j = i.split('\n')
    print j[0]
    h = max([int(i.split()[-1]) for i in j[1:]])
    for y in j[1:]:
        if str(h) == y.split()[-1].strip():
            print y


Query1 
Hit id 1a score 5
Query2
Hit id 2b score 2
>>>
```